# My bone is not letting me modify IK limits

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

First of all I'm a very beginner in terms of blender at the point that I'm still doing a course in Udemy, now we are on the rigging part of the blender course and I got my first issue.

We are trying to limit IK bones and every bone is working well except the root bone that have all the limit and IK options grayed out (more in the picture down there).

so as I did in my course forums I will give a checklist of what I did and checked:

- it has no bone constraints applied
- is parented with the base bone (the cycle on the picture that helps me move all the lamp)
- when it had rotation lock with the bone constraint one it worked (which is not needed for the IK limiting that we are doing now on the course)
- Auto IK is checked
- Is not on rest position
- it has rotation and scale applied

[image]

I'll upload the blend file if it you think it's gonna help.

[image]

Comment: Here you can learn everything about IK. It's very detailed: https://youtu.be/gq7K1mX4pRI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root bone is not part of the IK chain (you've set a *Chain Length* of 3) so all the limit values are greyed.

Comment: Oh... well it was a good mistake to learn as a beginner, thanks for the help! you helped me a lot!